# Should winter sport be renamed ice sports?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I suspect 90% of [wintersport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wintersport) questions will be about [snow-sports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snow-sports). Is 90% of one tag being another, more specific tag a problem?

Should people wanting to know if they can go bobsledding in the Carribean use something like [ice-sports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ice-sports) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think [snow-sports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snow-sports) OR [ice-sports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ice-sports) are useful tags.

99% of people, when asked to categorise bob-sledding or skiing or ice skating or anything involving snow and/or ice, are going to call it "winter sports". I don't see why a subdivision of [wintersport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wintersport) is necessary considering that people who are experts about "snow-sports" are probably going to know a lot about "ice-sports" as well, considering that in a lot of situations the terms are interchangeable.

I just don't think that most people would even think to search the term "snow-sports".

Comment: You forget that we can always make synonym mappings.

Comment: I think merging "snow sports" into "winter sports" makes more sense than renaming "winter sports" to "ice sports". If we did that then pretty soon we'd get a question about a winter sport involving neither snow nor ice, not that I can think of one right now (-: